# Apply background-size to individual layer of a multiple background

Tags: css, background-image

Just discovered multiple background. I would like to know how can you apply determined properties to only one of these backgrounds of your list of a multiple background. How can you **target it individually**?

Here is an example to illustrate:

```
body{
    background:
        url(images/small-group-bubbles.png) repeat-x fixed 10% 0,
        url(images/blur-bubble.png) repeat-x fixed -130% 0,
        url(images/big-bubble.png) repeat-x fixed 40% 0,
        url(images/green-gra-bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: #87d677;
```

As you can see there is a list of multiple backgrounds, but I would like to make one of these elements cover the whole screen with background-size. This code of course applies the cover property to all the images. I would like this cover property be applied only to the last picture: green-gra-bg/jpg.

How can I do this?

Comment: Thanks to Dylan the answer is pretty straight forward. You can adjust each layer by changing the code in the shorthand of each image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can specify the size inline for each background url:

[image]

Here's the link: http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/

so for example, use /cover below on your last url

```
body{
    background:
        url(images/small-group-bubbles.png) repeat-x fixed 10% 0,
        url(images/blur-bubble.png) repeat-x fixed -130% 0,
        url(images/big-bubble.png) repeat-x fixed 40% 0,
        url(images/green-gra-bg.jpg) no-repeat center/cover fixed;
    background-color: #87d677;
}
```

for my own personal example I tested an example i found: 
http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/get-grips-css3-multiple-background-images

```
body {
    background: 
        url(imgs/cloud.png) top center/800px no-repeat, 
        url(imgs/clouds-scatter.png) -46% -330px/500px repeat-x, 
        url(imgs/hills.png) bottom center repeat-x, 
        url(imgs/peaks.png) bottom right repeat-x;
}
```

The 800px and 500px sizes I add appear to be affecting each layer independent from one another.

Comment: Thanks for the help in understanding this. What I don't get is the CSS syntax. What does "\" exactly do when placed between center and cover? It seems to work but I dont understand why...

Comment: Yeah it's strange syntax and I beleive it's just shorthand. I've seen this in other spots such as when doing font styles. Sometimes you'll see something like.

font: bold italic small-caps 1em/1.5em verdana,sans-serif

The / lets you write the font-size and line-height properties together more easily.

Comment: Even so, this is applying cover to all the image layers. Or as the last image has a cover property all the rest inherit this? Answering regarding the symbol "/" if you take it out it does not work anymore. Strange...

Comment: I would like also to remark to Dylan and other users that the question is how to target only one image layer of the multiple background.

Comment: it does work individually, but you may also need to specify position.