# Apply background-size to multiple background CSS line

Tags: css, background-image

I want to add a linear gradient and an image as background for an element.

I do it as follows:

```
.home_description .perchas{
background:linear-gradient(140deg, rgba(28,121,192,0.85) 0%, rgba(3,137,255,0.85) 100%), url('/assets/img/perchas.jpg');
}
```

It works as expected.

But now, if I apply the `background-size: cover;` property, it does not work ( = image shows as default in full original size).

Reading this question: [Apply background-size to individual layer of a multiple background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16194737/apply-background-size-to-individual-layer-of-a-multiple-background)

I tried

```
.home_description .perchas{
background:linear-gradient(140deg, rgba(28,121,192,0.85) 0%, rgba(3,137,255,0.85) 100%), url('/assets/img/perchas.jpg') no-repeat center/cover fixed;
}
```

But it still won't apply the cover size (in this case the image shows centered).

Full context on Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/da9bm7ce/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting:

```
background-image: <background-image-1>, <background-image-2>, ... <background-image-N>;
```

So you have to set:

```
background-size: <background-size-1>, <background-size-2>, ... <background-size-N>;
```

```css
.perchas {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background: linear-gradient(140deg, rgba(28, 121, 192, 0.85) 0%, rgba(3, 137, 255, 0.85) 100%), 
  url('https://via.placeholder.com/150');
  background-position: center;
  background-size: auto, cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="perchas"></div>
```

**Updated** code from your jsfiddle:

```css
.home_description {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.home_description h1 {
  display: block;
}

.home_description .box {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 2.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  color: #FFF;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: auto, cover;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 24.25%;
}

.home_description .spacer {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 1%;
}

.home_description .box.perchas {
  background-image: linear-gradient(140deg, rgba(28, 121, 192, 0.85) 0%, rgba(3, 137, 255, 0.85) 100%), url('https://via.placeholder.com/150');
}

.home_description .box.bici {
  background-image: linear-gradient(140deg, rgba(28, 121, 192, 0.85) 0%, rgba(3, 137, 255, 0.85) 100%), url('https://via.placeholder.com/90');
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>

  <div class="home_description">

    <h1>Whatever</h1>
    <!--

    -->
    <div class="box perchas">
      <h2>Mobiliario</h2>
      <p>Nuestros elementos.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <!--

    -->
    <div class="box perchas">
      <h2>Atención 24h</h2>
      <p>Con nosotros, nunca estás solo....</p>
    </div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <!--

    -->
    <div class="box perchas">
      <h2>Sin gastos adicionales</h2>
      <p>Nuestros precios incluyen costes.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <!--

    -->
    <div class="box perchas">
      <h2>Tarjeta X</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsumistic.</p>
    </div>
    <!--

-->
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried your version but it does not work. This fiddle shows more of the real situation, where the property `display:table-cell;` may be affecting too - https://jsfiddle.net/da9bm7ce/1/ (you can see the cover size is not being considered)

Comment: @AlvaroFranz, styles are cascading, so you've just rewritten `background-size` and `background-position` with `background` shorthand added later. See the updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1xozme8g/)

Comment: @AlvaroFranz, happy to help.